# Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/usr/lib/nodejs:/usr/lib/node_modules:/usr/share/javascript/app/models

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ubuntu, express

I am trying to run a [project](https://github.com/sdelements/lets-chat) . but its giving an error

> ```
> fs.js:666
>   return binding.readdir(pathModule._makeLong(path));
>                  ^
> Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/usr/lib/nodejs:/usr/lib/node_modules:/usr/share/javascript/app/models'
>     at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:666:18)
>     at require_tree (/home/shubham/Documents/Node/lets-chat/node_modules/require-tree/index.js:37:24)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/shubham/Documents/Node/lets-chat/app.js:33:14)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
>     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
>     at startup (node.js:119:16)
>     at node.js:935:3
>
> npm ERR! lets-chat@0.4.2 start: `node app.js`
> npm ERR! Exit status 8
> npm ERR! 
> npm ERR! Failed at the lets-chat@0.4.2 start script.
> npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the lets-chat package,
> npm ERR! not with npm itself.
> npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
> npm ERR!     node app.js
> npm ERR! You can get their info via:
> npm ERR!     npm owner ls lets-chat
> npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
> npm ERR! System Linux 3.16.0-49-generic
> npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
> npm ERR! cwd /home/shubham/Documents/Node/lets-chat
> npm ERR! node -v v0.10.37
> npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! 
> npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /home/shubham/Documents/Node/lets-chat/npm-debug.log
> npm ERR! not ok code 0
> ```

and **app.js** file is:

```
'use strict';

process.title = 'letschat';

require('colors');

var _ = require('lodash'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    express = require('express.oi'),
    i18n = require('i18n'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
    compression = require('compression'),
    helmet = require('helmet'),
    http = require('http'),
    nunjucks = require('nunjucks'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    migroose = require('./migroose'),
    connectMongo = require('connect-mongo'),
    all = require('require-tree'),
    psjon = require('./package.json'),
    settings = require('./app/config'),
    auth = require('./app/auth/index'),
    core = require('./app/core/index');

var MongoStore = connectMongo(express.session),
    httpEnabled = settings.http && settings.http.enable,
    httpsEnabled = settings.https && settings.https.enable,
    models = all('./app/models'),
    middlewares = all('./app/middlewares'),
    controllers = all('./app/controllers'),
    app;

//
// express.oi Setup
//
if (httpsEnabled) {
     app = express().https({
        key: fs.readFileSync(settings.https.key),
        cert: fs.readFileSync(settings.https.cert)
    }).io();
} else {
    app = express().http().io();
}

if (settings.env === 'production') {
    app.set('env', settings.env);
    app.set('json spaces', undefined);
    app.enable('view cache');
}

// Session
var sessionStore = new MongoStore({
    url: settings.database.uri,
    autoReconnect: true
});

// Session
var session = {
    key: 'connect.sid',
    secret: settings.secrets.cookie,
    store: sessionStore,
    cookie: { secure: httpsEnabled },
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
};

// Set compression before any routes
app.use(compression({ threshold: 512 }));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.io.session(session);

auth.setup(app, session, core);

// Security protections
app.use(helmet.frameguard());
app.use(helmet.hidePoweredBy());
app.use(helmet.ieNoOpen());
app.use(helmet.noSniff());
app.use(helmet.xssFilter());
app.use(helmet.hsts({
    maxAge: 31536000,
    includeSubdomains: true,
    force: httpsEnabled,
    preload: true
}));
app.use(helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
    defaultSrc: ['\'none\''],
    connectSrc: ['*'],
    scriptSrc: ['\'self\'', '\'unsafe-eval\''],
    styleSrc: ['\'self\'', 'fonts.googleapis.com', '\'unsafe-inline\''],
    fontSrc: ['\'self\'', 'fonts.gstatic.com'],
    mediaSrc: ['\'self\''],
    objectSrc: ['\'self\''],
    imgSrc: ['*']
}));

var bundles = {};
app.use(require('connect-assets')({
    paths: [
        'media/js',
        'media/less'
    ],
    helperContext: bundles,
    build: settings.env === 'production',
    fingerprinting: settings.env === 'production',
    servePath: 'media/dist'
}));

// Public
app.use('/media', express.static(__dirname + '/media', {
    maxAge: '364d'
}));

// Templates
var nun = nunjucks.configure('templates', {
    autoescape: true,
    express: app,
    tags: {
        blockStart: '<%',
        blockEnd: '%>',
        variableStart: '<$',
        variableEnd: '$>',
        commentStart: '<#',
        commentEnd: '#>'
    }
});

function wrapBundler(func) {
    // This method ensures all assets paths start with "./"
    // Making them relative, and not absolute
    return function() {
        return func.apply(func, arguments)
                   .replace(/href="\//g, 'href="./')
                   .replace(/src="\//g, 'src="./');
    };
}

nun.addFilter('js', wrapBundler(bundles.js));
nun.addFilter('css', wrapBundler(bundles.css));
nun.addGlobal('text_search', false);

// i18n
i18n.configure({
    directory: __dirname + '/locales',
    defaultLocale: settings.i18n && settings.i18n.locale || 'en'
});
app.use(i18n.init);

// HTTP Middlewares
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

// IE header
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('X-UA-Compatible', 'IE=Edge,chrome=1');
    next();
});

//
// Controllers
//
_.each(controllers, function(controller) {
    controller.apply({
        app: app,
        core: core,
        settings: settings,
        middlewares: middlewares,
        models: models,
        controllers: controllers
    });
});

//
// Mongo
//

mongoose.connection.on('error', function (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
});

mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function() {
    throw new Error('Could not connect to database');
});

//
// Go Time
//

function startApp() {
    var port = httpsEnabled && settings.https.port ||
               httpEnabled && settings.http.port;

    var host = httpsEnabled && settings.https.host ||
               httpEnabled && settings.http.host || '0.0.0.0';



    if (httpsEnabled && httpEnabled) {
        // Create an HTTP -> HTTPS redirect server
        var redirectServer = express();
        redirectServer.get('*', function(req, res) {
            var urlPort = port === 80 ? '' : ':' + port;
            res.redirect('https://' + req.hostname + urlPort + req.path);
        });
        http.createServer(redirectServer)
            .listen(settings.http.port || 5000, host);
    }

    app.listen(port, host);

    //
    // XMPP
    //
    if (settings.xmpp.enable) {
        var xmpp = require('./app/xmpp/index');
        xmpp(core);
    }

    var art = fs.readFileSync('./app/misc/art.txt', 'utf8');
    console.log('\n' + art + '\n\n' + 'Release ' + psjon.version.yellow + '\n');
}

function checkForMongoTextSearch() {
    if (!mongoose.mongo || !mongoose.mongo.Admin) {
        // MongoDB API has changed, assume text search is enabled
        nun.addGlobal('text_search', true);
        return;
    }

    var admin = new mongoose.mongo.Admin(mongoose.connection.db);
    admin.buildInfo(function (err, info) {
        if (err || !info) {
            return;
        }

        var version = info.version.split('.');
        if (version.length < 2) {
            return;
        }

        if(version[0] < 2) {
            return;
        }

        if(version[0] === '2' && version[1] < 6) {
            return;
        }

        nun.addGlobal('text_search', true);
    });
}

mongoose.connect(settings.database.uri, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    checkForMongoTextSearch();

    migroose.needsMigration(function(err, migrationRequired) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        }

        else if (migrationRequired) {
            console.log('Database migration required'.red);
            console.log('Ensure you backup your database first.');
            console.log('');
            console.log(
                'Run the following command: ' + 'npm run migrate'.yellow
            );

            return process.exit();
        }

        startApp();
    });
});
```

Comment: Did you run `npm install`?

Comment: yes that successfully done

Answer (score 1):

You have to run `npm install` in the root directory, then I found there is a very old dependency you should change, do this:

Open file `package.json` and replace this:

```
"passport": "^0.2.2",
"passport-http": "^0.2.2",
```

With this:

```
"passport": "~0.3",
"passport-http": "~0.3",
```

Then run `npm install`

And when ready run `npm start`

It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This error can be frustrating and inconsistent, the solution is Uninstall the packages locally and globally and reinstall with suitable versions or update the modules.

Trying to upgrade the modules without uninstalling sometimes causes this error

```
npm uninstall <package>
npm uninstall <package> -g

npm install <package>
```